# a matrix with variables in line and computations in column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I have to analyse.

For each column of my dataframe, I compute some calculus, like `mean`, `min` or `max`.

I want to display my results as a matrix like this :

```
+--------+------+----+-----+-----+
|        | mean | sd | min | max |
+--------+------+----+-----+-----+
| age    | 55   | 10 | 22  | 89  |
+--------+------+----+-----+-----+
| height | 175  | 12 | 160 | 190 |
+--------+------+----+-----+-----+
| weight | 70   | 15 | 50  | 110 |
+--------+------+----+-----+-----+
```

How can I do so ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 <- df1 %>%
        select(age, height, weight) %>%
        gather %>%
        group_by(key) %>% 
        summarise(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value), min = min(value), max = max(value))
m1 <- as.matrix(d1[-1])
rownames(m1) <- d1[[1]]
m1
#          mean        sd       min       max
#age     29.72114 1.1530639  25.53044  31.51712 
#height 170.13357 0.9731242 168.43238 171.77091
#weight  59.69239 0.7826297  58.00708  61.05686
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(24), age = rnorm(24, 30), height = rnorm(24, 170),
         weight  = rnorm(24, 60))
```

Comment: Great, thank you ! What if I want to select all columns ? If I remove the `select` line, every summarised value is NA

Comment: @DanChaltiel  Here, in the example I used an extra column.  So, if you want to select all the columns, remove the `select`, The reason you could be getting NA is because the columns may have some NA elements, so, use `mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)`, `sd(value, na.rm = TRUE)` etc.  Also, here, I am assuming that you have all numeric columns.  If it is not, then it will mix non-numeric with numeric can cause problems